# ComObject Method does not exist

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, windows-update

I am currently attempting to work with the `PSWindowsUpdate` Module provided [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2d191bcd-3308-4edd-9de2-88dff796b0bc). When using the `WUInstall` cmdlet I am getting an error when a new COM object is made. There are two commands involved.

```
$objSession = New-Object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.Session
$objSearcher = $objSession.CreateUpdateSearcher()
```

Unfortunately when running this, the device I am on is claiming that the COM object does not contain the method `CreateUpdateSearcher()`. This has worked on every other machine that I have worked on. Is there a way I can fix this error? Has anybody experienced this before? The PC I am attempting it on is using PowerShell v2.0. I have used this on another v2.0 machine as well so that shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: where's the error message?

Comment: The first line of your code snippet is missing a double quote at the end. Is that a typo in your question or in your actual code? Also, please add the actual error message to your question.